# JavaScript array returns length 0

Tags: javascript, arrays, electron

I am writing code for a simple electron based application, while working with a list of directory array its started acting weird!

Take a look at this picture:

[image]

At first when i `console.log( dirs )` it displays all of its array elements in the console, but while using the `length` it show it has 0 elements! Which is not true.

Again in the loop its not traversing!

Also I am not using `push` method to insert new objects and `arr.slice()` also returns 0 array elements!

Am i missing something here?

Comment: Try `console.log(dirs.slice())`

Comment: Weird. For of was supposed to iterate a property sequence in this array

Comment: @Oriol Hi, adding `dirs.slice()` would also return `Array[0]` Here is the screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYs0n.png

Comment: Its not a dup. i am not inserting any new items using push like that...

Comment: Well, there is something that fills your array between your `console.log` and it being displayed in the console. Blame Chrome's devtools for being misleading. I suggest using better devtools.

Comment: This is the only dev tool available in electron, btw what you think about the loop? I did all kinds of loops to see if the child elements are there or not,, it does nothing .. i checked your marked dup. Q. its making no sense

Comment: That's because there are no elements. The array is empty, as shown by `dirs.slice()`. It's just that the array is populated *later*.

Comment: `items` variable is already populated with valid informations..

Comment: Can you try with `dirs=[1,2,3]` instead of `dirs=items['directories']`?

Comment: @sabithpocker No, that shows undefined!

Comment: I think dat's a troll... It looks like yourself planned it, you put elaborated images at the question with this intention, isn't it? Or this array may have secret getters/setters, or even proxies.

Comment: Can you try `delete console.log` / `delete window.console` before using it. To restore `console.log` in browser if it was modified by your framework.

Comment: @FREEZE No! Why you even think that! Oriol was right, data was targeted before the array populates!